# Create or remove GDI shapes on command

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I'm creating a win32 application. on the main window there are 5 buttons. in front of each button there is a small circle drawn. (using GDI tools. in case WM_PAINT). now when I press on a button the circle in front of it should colour in red colour. how can I do this.

If we create a edit box any time we can change the text on it using SendMessege to it. like that is it possible to change the colour on shapes drawn earlier.

Please can someone give me an advice.

```
case WM_PAINT:
    {
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hDC;
    HBRUSH brusha;

    hDC=BeginPaint(hWnd,&ps);       
    brusha=CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,255,0));
    SelectObject(hDC,brusha);
    Ellipse(hDC, 20, 20, 50, 50);
    DeleteObject(brusha);
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }

 case WM_COMMAND:
      switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
            case BUTTON:
            {
             //here I need to change the above drawn corcle to be red.
            }
        }
```

Comment: Lots of ways to do that. What language are you using C++ ?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson YES im using C++.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson so please give me an advice on how to do this type of thing.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I'm waiting for your help. i'm using c++, mingw compiler. please explain me how to do this. I googled this and refered some tutorials, but cant get eny idea about this.

Comment: Would appear Mark Ransom has pointed you in the edirection I would have now I'ves een the code you have. Click Changes the colour and forces a repaint. Pretty much the way it should be done in any language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the color of an already drawn image, but you can redraw it. Use the Windows function `InvalidateRect` to tell the control that it needs to be redrawn, and you will get another call to your `WM_PAINT` handler. In the handler select the desired color before you draw your circle.

Comment: I added my code above. can u kindly teach me how to add this to the above code

Comment: @LakshanPerera, make a variable to contain the current color. Initialize the color to green. In the `WM_COMMAND` handler set the variable to red, then call `InvalidateRect`.

Comment: @MarkRanson  in above code in case BUTTON I added this lines `brusha=CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,0,0));
 InvalidateRect(hWnd,NULL,false);` it compiled without errors. but when the button clicks nothing happens.

Comment: enyway this answer gave me a idea, ill try some experements and find a method. thanks in help